Question About this Sine Equation’s Solution Set
Within the interval of [0, 2$\pi$),
Why are the solutions to $\sin^2 3x - \sin^2 x = 0$ (when graphed on Desmos) $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ and not $0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{7\pi}{4}$
My thought for the latter was that the solutions for $\sin^2 3x - \sin^2 x = 0$ must also include the solutions for sine, which for example, can be 0. However, 0 nor other sine x-intercepts such as $\pi$ are in the solution. Why is this?
Thank you for your time.

Welcome to MSE.  Who says $0$ is not a solution?

When I graph it on Desmos, 0 nor the others mentioned are part of the solution set.

When I graph it they are; cf. this

I graphed it as the equation setting it equal to 0

you must be generating some computational artifact like rounding error

So the actual answer includes 0?

Yes, the solutions are $n\pi/4$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, including $0$

When I tried what you said you did in Desmos, it gave me $x=0$ but not the other multiples of $\frac\pi2$. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that all of those zeros are where the graph is tangent to the $x$ axis but doesn't cross it. Numeric methods are not good at finding those kinds of zeros; if you have two points very close to the root they still both have the same sign and there is never a numeric indication that there is a root.

In most cases where Desmos finds roots, it does so because the function goes from positive to negative (or negative to positive) as it passes the root. Numerical methods easily find such roots.

using $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$ and the trigonometric pythagoras $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, one can rewrite your expression as
$16 \sin^6 x - 24 \sin^4 x + 8 \sin^2 x = 0$
This can be factored to:
$\sin^2 x (\sin^2 x - 1) (\sin^2 x - \frac12) = 0$
Each factor defines a (sub)set of solutions $x$:

$\sin^2 x = 0$ $\quad x \in \{0;\pi\}$

$\sin^2 x = 1$ $\quad x \in \{\frac{\pi}{2}; \frac32 \pi\}$

$\sin^2 x = \frac12$ $\quad x \in \{ \frac14 \pi; \frac34 \pi; \frac54 \pi; \frac74 \pi\}$


These are all eight solutions of your initial equation.
Regarding Desmos, can you add a screenshot of the in- and output?

Here

Write the equation as $(\sin(3x)-\sin(x))(\sin(3x)+\sin(x))=0$ .

It is the same result on my side

My goal was to get rid of any additional factor within sin to simplify the equation and show all solutions.
